# 3 Table Database on MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Is it possible to join 3 tables on MySQL on which final output will show sample below.

Table1

```
Dog     2
Cat     3
```

Table2

```
Dog     1
Cow     3
```

Table3

```
Cat     1
Rat     3
```

Final Output

```
Dog     3
Cat     4
Rat     3
Cow     3
```

Updated Output

```html
Thanks, but how to do if the output is like below.<br><table>
  <tr>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Table 1</th><th>Table 2</th><th>Table 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td>3</td><td>0</td><td>1</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Cow</td>
    <td>0</td><td>3</td><td>0</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Rat</td>
    <td>0</td><td>0</td><td>3</td>
  </tr></table>
```

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` and then aggregate the result on the animal column. This isn't a join problem.

Comment: @danblack thanks, do you know also how to update data on output when new data is updated on any of the tables, i mean the most efficient way not just using timer or delay to fetch data.

Comment: Nothing sane. SQL isn't designed as an event service. Is this query slow? Why do you have three tables having the same data anyway?

Comment: @danblack i just want an efficient way of retrieving data from the database not using interval, time or delay loop. Page will just update data if there is a changes on the data on the tables and not fetch data like every 30 seconds.

Comment: Its a new question, requires information on how up to date you want things, how is data populated, why you have 3 tables etc.

Comment: Its a comparison between 3 tables on which the data is gathered on 3 separate programs. items on program 1 does not means it is present to on program 2 or 3. That is why i am trying to get all same items on the 3 tables as well as showing also those unique items on each tables

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union statement to merge the three tables together and then select from them together like this:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    SUM(column2)
FROM
(
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column2, column2 FROM Table3
)
GROUP BY column1
```

If your column names are different across the three tables, you would need to alias the column names.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks! I updated my answer. That makes much more sense.